# Path for Rails Active Storage Blog in VueJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, vue.js, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage in a Rails 5.2 app using AWS S3 to host the images.  I can use `<%= image_tag @gin.pic %>` ok in a HTML view, but I'm using a seperate VueJS front-end app driven from the Rails API and I'm struggling with the file path and just getting a load of 404s.

I initially tried `<img v-bind:src="gin.pic" alt="" />` with no luck so tried the below alternatives too:

**components/Gins.vue**

```
...
<img v-bind:src="'http://localhost:3000/gins/' + gin.pic_file_name" alt="" />
...
```

and

```
... 
<img v-bind:src="'http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/' + 
gin.pic_file_name" alt="" /> 
...
```

Neither of the above work.

I've looked at the source code from the HTML app, and it gives the URL as:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--cea3da3ea500428a5f9827bb6bfd490ace800a8c/bathtub.jpg
```

This of course redirects to the URL in S3.

But where do I get the parameter after `blobs`?  This doesn't appear to the `key` value from the `active_storage_blobs` table.

Comment: assuming `gin` is an object with your rails instance model, in your Vue component just try `<img :src="gin.pic" />` (juste like the `image_tag` helper).

Comment: Sorry, should have said that's how I initially tried it. Post updated.

Comment: if `@gin.pic` returns you the active_storage url, maybe try to pass it as a props of your component directly and use it inside Vue for your img src

Comment: Moving forwards I intend to only use the Rails app as API only, so not sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The segment between `/rails/active_storage/blobs/` and the filename in the URL you posted is a signed blob ID. Here’s how to obtain it in Ruby:

```
@gin.pic.signed_id
```

I’m not familiar with Vue, so I don’t know how you’d expose that value to your Vue app. Hopefully that’s enough to help you.

If it’s possible, I’d recommend returning the full download URL in the API response from the Rails app rather than assembling it in your Vue app from disparate data. Exactly how you’d do that depends on how you’re rendering API responses, but the key bit is using [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) or `rails_blob_url` to generate the URL:

```
url_for(@gin.pic)
rails_blob_url(@gin.pic)
```

`url_for` and `rails_blob_url` are equivalent in the example above. Given the same attached file, they generate the same URL.